# oracle sql query finding rows with multiple values in 3rd column matching columns 1 and 2

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dataset with about a million rows in and Oracle 11 db.
I'd like to find rows where col1 and col2 match but have different values in col3.
I'm not sure how to do this well though i can certainly write a query that never seems to finish:

```
select col1,col2,col3 
from table tab1 
where exists 
(select 1 
from table tab2 
where tab1.col1 = tab2.col1 
  and tab1.col2 = tab2.col2 
  and tab1.col3 != tab2.col3);
```

I ran this and after an hour gave up waiting - I need to analyze the problems and present it to some people for figuring out how to move forward.

Thanks in any case,
Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A query like this will indicate which rows having the same `col1, col2` have differing values in `col3`:

```
SELECT col1, col2
  FROM x
  GROUP BY col1, col2
  HAVING MIN(col3) <> MAX(col3)
```

To see how many of this `col1, col2` pairs are affected:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT col1, col2
          FROM x
          GROUP BY col1, col2
          HAVING MIN(col3) <> MAX(col3)
        )
```

You may also wish to know how many duplicates there are (ie having `col1, col2, col3` the same:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
  FROM x
  GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Hi. I ended up doing this but your response made me think better. thanks. 
    select *
from mytable where (col1,col2) in
(
select col1,col2 from
(
SELECT col1,col2,col3 from mytable group by col1,col2,col3
)
group by col1,col2 having count(*) > 1
)
order by col1,col2;

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```
select col1,col2,col3 
from table tab1 
where col1 = col2
and col1 <> col3
```

Comment: No basically the col1 and col2 and col 3 make up a logical key but col1 and col2 are a database key- some bad data got SQL'D in and I'd like to see how bad the problem is. So I want to find rows matching in col1 and col2 BUT not matching on col 3

Comment: @JeffKish Please provide your data sample.